# TinyMce how to upload multiple Images in a Post into same upload folder and how to stop imagetools to create Blob

Tags: javascript, php, tinymce, tinymce-4

I have 2 Problems I can't seem to find a solution for. I use
Laravel 5.6
Vue JS Component
TinyMCE 4.9.1

I have crated a vueJs Component for my Form which includes TinyMce and it all seems to work so far. On the Server side I create a folder for each Post I create and the Folder Name gets saved in the Post Table so when I delete a Post the Folder with all the Photos should be deleted. 
First of all, I have a understanding Problem. I thought that if I set  **automatic_uploads: false,** 
the Photo would not be uploaded straight away, but it does. If that would not happen, then my first Problem would be fixed, because all Photos would be uploaded at the same time.

Lets supply the Sourcecode for a better understanding:

**my vueJs Component**

```
<template>
<div>
  <form method="post" action="" @submit.prevent="onSubmit">
  <fieldset class="add-form"><legend class="add-form">
  <h3>Article Details</h3></legend>
  <label class="required" for="fname">Headline</label>
  <input class="form-control"  v-model="post.title" id="fname">
  <span class="invalid-feedback" v-text="errors.get('title')"></span>
  <input class="form-control"  v-model="folder" id="folder">
  <tinymce v-model="post.body"
    :plugins="myPlugins" 
    :toolbar ="myToolbar1"
    :init="myInit"
  >
  </tinymce>

<script>
import Editor from '@tinymce/tinymce-vue';
// Import TinyMCE
import tinymce from 'tinymce/tinymce';
// A theme is also required
import 'tinymce/themes/modern/theme';


export default{
    components: {
           'tinymce': Editor // <- Important part
    },

    data () { 
            return { 
            name: 'app',
            folder: null,
            myModel:'',
            theme: "modern",
            myToolbar1: 'undo redo | bold italic underline forecolor backcolor | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | hr bullist numlist outdent indent | link image table | code preview',
            myPlugins: "link image code preview imagetools table lists textcolor hr wordcount",

            myInit: {
                setup: function(editor){
                    automatic_uploads: false, 
                    editor.on('NodeChange', function (e) {
                      if(e.element.tagName === "IMG"){          
                        //e.element.setAttribute("data-original", e.element.currentSrc);
                       // e.element.setAttribute("src", newSrc);
                      }
                    });

                },

                images_dataimg_filter: function(img) {
                    return false;
                    return img.hasAttribute('internal-blob');
                },
                convert_urls : false,
                height:500,
                automatic_uploads: false, 
                images_upload_base_path: '/../../',
                relative_urls : false,


                // override default upload handler to simulate successful upload
                images_upload_handler: function (blobInfo, success, failure) {
                    var xhr, formData;
                    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    xhr.withCredentials = false;
                    xhr.open('POST', '/memberarea/api/upload-image');
                    var token = document.head.querySelector("[name=csrf-token]").content;
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRF-Token", token);

                    xhr.onload = function() {
                        var json;
                        var folder2;
                        if (xhr.status != 200) {
                            failure('HTTP Error: ' + xhr.status);
                            return;
                        }
                        json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

                        if (!json || typeof json.location != 'string') {
                            failure('Invalid JSON: ' + xhr.responseText);
                            return;
                        }
                        success(json.location);

                        this.folder = json.folder;
                    };

                    formData = new FormData();
                    formData.append('file', blobInfo.blob(), blobInfo.filename());
                    xhr.send(formData);
                }                
            },               
            result:[],
            "post": {     
                title: '',
                teaser:'',
                body: '',
                tags:[],

            }, 

            errors: new Errors(),
            availableTags:'',
            tags:[],

             }},

    computed: {},

    mounted: function () {
            this.getTags();
        },

        methods: {

            getTags(){

                axios.get('/api/tags/id')
                         .then((response) => {
                            this.availableTags = response.data;
                        })
                        .catch(function () {
                        });

            },

       onSubmit(){
       {      
                let uri = '/admin/news/save-post';

                var input = this.post;


                    axios.post(uri, input)
                        .then((response) => {
                          window.location.href = response.data.redirect;
                        })
                       .catch(error => this.errors.record(error.response.data.errors));

                }

           }


        }            
    }
```

**The Image Controller to upload the Image:**

```
 public function uploadImages()
 {
    $folder = uniqid();
    if (!\Storage::exists($folder)) {
            \Storage::disk('posts')->makeDirectory($folder);
    }

    $imgpath = \Storage::disk('posts')->put($folder,request()->file('file'));

    return \Response::json(['folder' => $folder, 'location' => '/storage/uploads/posts/'.$imgpath]);
 }
```

I have now got the following Problem. I select a Photo, a Folder gets created the Photo uploaded. If I add another Photo a new Folder gets created instead of uploading it into the same Folder. So I thought to return the Foldername from the Upload Function back to the Component, save it in a hidden Input Field and sent it back to the Upload Method again, unfortunately I fail already to set the Value into the Hidden Input Field. Question now, how can that be solved best? any suggestion welcome.

Second Problem, I integrated the imagetools Plugin, but as soon I use it it turns the Image into a Blob. again I do not understand the instructions correctly, but I thought by adding below it would switch this off, but no luck. So I might have an Image saved as a Blob and at the same time saved in a Folder and the next time only the Path is saved in the database. How can I solve this?

```
  images_dataimg_filter: function(img) {
                return false;
               // return img.hasAttribute('internal-blob');
            },
```

Answer (score 0):

For your first problem, according to tinymce documentation [automatic_upload](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/file-image-upload/#automatic_uploads) will do nothing if images_upload_url is not specified. If you implement [images_upload_url](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/file-image-upload/#images_upload_url) upload will get triggered whenever you call editor.uploadImages().